# Excel Open, Modify, Save with a spreadsheet on teams

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, save-as

So i have a macro that runs to update another workbook.  everything is doing what it is supposed to, even if i walk through the process.  i can see what it is doing and everything is correct.  the issue is at the bottom when i have opened the file i need to update, edit the correct(which it does), save it, (which it says it did), and close it back down.  but when i open the destination to check, there is no changes made.  the code is below, i will say the file it is trying to change is under a teams folder.  it has no issues opening the correct file, just saving.  any help would be great.

```
Sub EditCell()

    Where = ActiveCell.Column
    Select Case Where
        Case 10, 14, 15, 16
            SelCol = "YesNo"
        Case 11, 12, 27
            SelCol = "Comment"
    End Select
    
    If SelCol = "YesNo" Then
        Answer = MsgBox("Please select.", vbYesNo, "Yes/No")
        TitleName = Cells(1, Where).Value
        IRBNetID = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).Value
        Workbooks.Open ("https://sharepoint.com/files/Testing.xlsx")
        Workbooks("Testing").Activate
        FindCol = WorksheetFunction.Match(TitleName, Range("A1:BB1").Value, 0)
        FindRow = WorksheetFunction.Match(IRBNetID, Range("A1:A5000").Value, 0)
        If Answer = 6 Then
            Cells(FindRow, FindCol).Value = "Yes"
        Else
            Cells(FindRow, FindCol).Value = "No"
        End If
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Workbooks("Testing").SaveAs
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Workbooks("Testing").Close
        Workbooks("Test 2").RefreshAll
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the solution to this issue.  you have to disable the autosave feature, prior to saving the workbook. example below incase anyone wants to see the section i changed from above

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.AutoSaveOn = False '// this needs to be added
Workbooks("Testing").SaveAs
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Workbooks("Testing").Close
```